# OpenMDAO 0.13, connecting a component to an assembly within a bigger assembly

Tags: openmdao

Can anyone please advise how to connect and assembly to a component inside a larger assembly. I am looking for help to model a system something which looks like this.
Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you need to do something like:

> assembly2.create_passthrough('component5.input')

and then you can

> connect('component1.output', 'assembly2.input')

Comment: How do you add an assembly within another assembly ?

Comment: note that OpenMDAO v0.13 is no longer supported and not being actively developed. You should switch your modeling to 1.7.x

Comment: an assembly behaves just like a component (it is in fact a component, just a more complicated one) and is added in the same way as you would add any other component.

also, you should check out a more recent, supported version of OpenMDAO per Justin's comment.

Comment: Is it possible to have an assembly inside a component?, if so how can i connect variables of the component to the input variables of the assembly

Comment: @swryan After some struggle, we crafted an example problem. Our solution (see my answer to this question) does not use `create_passthrough`. What would be the benefit of using `create_passthrough`?

Comment: Is it possible to make the connection based on the output?,                                            Can I run an if loop inside the assembly?

Comment: @kilojoules create_passthrough() is just shorthand for adding an input/output var to the assembly and connecting them like you have done.

Answer (score 0):

For those who come across this, we were able to implement the connections shown in the diagram. We did not need to use `create_passthrough`.

```
from openmdao.main.api import Component, Assembly
from openmdao.main.datatypes.api import Float, Bool, Int, Str, Array, Enum

from openmdao.main.api import Assembly
from openmdao.examples.simple.paraboloid import Paraboloid

class New1(Assembly):

    x=Float(iotype='in')
    f_xy=Float(iotype='out')

    out=Float(iotype='out') 
    def configure(self):
        self.add('C5',Paraboloid())
        self.add('C6',Paraboloid())
        self.connect('x','C5.x')
        self.driver.workflow.add(['C5','C6'])   
        self.connect("C5.f_xy","C6.x")
        self.connect('C6.f_xy', 'f_xy')



class New(Assembly):

    def configure(self):
        self.add('C1',Paraboloid())
        self.add('C2',Paraboloid())
        self.add('C4',Paraboloid())
        self.add('A2',New1())
        self.connect("C1.f_xy","A2.x")
        self.connect("A2.f_xy", "C4.x")
        self.driver.workflow.add(['C1','C2','C4','A2'])

        self.connect("C1.f_xy","C2.x")
        self.connect("C2.f_xy","C4.y")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = New()

    a.C1.x = 2.3
    a.C1.y = 7.2
    a.C2.y = 9.8
    a.C4.x = 1.5

    a.run()

    print "C1 has output of %0.2f and C5 has input of %0.2f" % (a.C1.f_xy,a.A2.C5.x)
    print "C4 has input of %0.2f and C6 has output of %0.2f" % (a.C4.x,a.A2.C6.f_xy)
```

output:

```
C1 has output of 139.49 and C5 has input of 139.49
C4 has input of 347431722.56 and C6 has output of 347431722.56
```

**Edit**

Here is the same assembly with an outer optimization

```
from openmdao.main.api import Component, Assembly
from openmdao.main.datatypes.api import Float, Bool, Int, Str, Array, Enum
from openmdao.lib.drivers.api import SLSQPdriver
from openmdao.main.api import Assembly
from openmdao.examples.simple.paraboloid import Paraboloid

class New1(Assembly):

    x=Float(iotype='in')
    f_xy=Float(iotype='out')
    def configure(self):
        self.add('C5',Paraboloid())
        self.add('C6',Paraboloid())
        self.connect('x','C5.x')
        self.driver.workflow.add(['C5','C6'])   
        self.connect("C5.f_xy","C6.x")
        self.connect('C6.f_xy', 'f_xy')



class New(Assembly):
    x=Float(3., iotype='in')
    f_xy=Float(iotype='out')
    def configure(self):
        self.add('C1',Paraboloid())
        self.add('C2',Paraboloid())
        self.add('C4',Paraboloid())
        self.add('A2',New1())
        self.connect("A2.f_xy", "C4.x")
        self.driver.workflow.add(['C1','C2','C4','A2'])
        self.connect('x', 'A2.x')
        self.connect('A2.f_xy', 'f_xy')
        self.connect("C1.f_xy","C2.x")
        self.connect("C2.f_xy","C4.y")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    class optim(Assembly):
        def configure(self):
           self.add('driver', SLSQPdriver())
           self.add('modl', New())
           self.driver.workflow.add('modl')
           self.driver.add_parameter('modl.x', low=-2., high=2.)
           self.driver.add_objective('modl.f_xy')
    a = optim()
    print "C1 has output of %0.2f and C5 has input of %0.2f" % (a.modl.C1.f_xy,a.modl.A2.C5.x)
    print "C4 has input of %0.2f and C6 has output of %0.2f" % (a.modl.C4.x,a.modl.A2.C6.f_xy)
    print 'initial objective: ', a.modl.f_xy
    a.run()
    print 'optimized objective: ', a.modl.f_xy
    print "New has output of ", a.modl.f_xy
```

output:

```
C1 has output of 0.00 and C5 has input of 0.00
C4 has input of 0.00 and C6 has output of 0.00
initial objective:  0.0
optimized objective:  113.0
New has output of  113.0
```